# dont run php on my liux server

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4

i step by step install apache and php on my VPS
[Install Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)
[Install PHP7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04)

after install and config my apache and php i see my php code on page.

like this:

```
<?php

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Comment: what about `sudo a2enmod php7`? Impying tghe module has been installed (and set up) correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used two separate tutorials for installing Apache and PHP 7 individually. There are plenty of tutorials providing instructions for installing a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) that shows how to make them work together, e.g.

- HowtoForge: [Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) LAMP server tutorial with Apache, PHP 7, and MySQL](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/)
- DigitalOcean: [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- How to Ubuntu: [How to Install LAMP on Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu)

The main missing part here is that you haven't installed `libapache2-mod-php7.0`. Therefore, installing PHP 7 **for** Apache 2.4 would require:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: i need to Clear the previous version I installed?

Comment: Installing the missing package is probably enough.

Comment: Esa is right, you've mixed up a bit the tutorials. What you were looking for is a LAMP installation guide. Alto I recommend LEMP because NginX trumps now Apache in almost every way.

Comment: @EsaJokinen after install i have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928974/call-to-undefined-function-json-encode-ctype-digit-on-php7-ubuntu